# multiple backgrounds from different classes

Tags: css, background-image

I know that to stack backgrounds on a selector I do something like

```
.selector{
background: url(url1), url(url2);
}
```

How can I add backgrounds when using different classes? (like a base class that will have url1, and another class which will have url2)

like

```
.base{
background: url(url1);
}

.selector{
background: url(url2);
}
```

but stacked

Comment: You can't. You would have to use two separate elements stacked. CSS classes don't work like that. They override not merge

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CSS is a set of key-value pairs. The key being the selector, the rule being the set of attributes associated to values inside the curly brackets. This forms a rule. If you stack keys, then you are basically telling that the attribute values are common for all tags which match the selector. However, if you want to give more values to the same attribute, it is ambivalent and I am pretty sure it is not supported in CSS.

EDIT: Imagine the interpreter having to look at each attribute of each rule and count the number of commas and check whether the number of commas matches the number of commas in the selector except value selectors. It would slow down the interpretation and would be nonsensical too.

Comment: To be more precise, if the same key is set for a given element, with different values, only the one with highest score will be applied. This is how CSS works.

Comment: I believe I might have been not clear-enough. I have been talking about stack keys and why stacked attributes are not allowed. I have not talked about priorities, because priorities are not related to the question. Your statement is valid, but I do not know what did you consider imprecise in my answer?